# Oracle Apex Accessing applications without login from a main application in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a problem in APEX version 20.2

I have a main application that has several links to applications. How can I solve the problem so that I don't have to enter a password in those applications, but only in the main one, but at the same time in these applications I was displayed as a user with the same login as in the first one

I found something in authentication scheme in session sharing. But i don't know

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to have something like a single sign on.

If that's so, then: if all those applications are in the same workspace (because it won't work if they are not):

- in "main" application, go to Shared Components > Authentication Schemes > choose Current schema > Session Sharing type set to „Custom“ > Session Cookie Attributes > enter e.g. `MY_SSO_COOKIE` into "Cookie name"
- main application should have some kind of a menu which is used to navigate among all other applications. Its query might look like this:

  ```
  select 
    null,
    app_name labelValue,
    'http://server_name:8084/apex/f?p=' || id_app ||':1:&SESSION.' targetValue,
    null is_current
  from applications
  where id_app in (select id_app from oper_x_app
                   where username = :APP_USER
                  )
  order by app_name
  ```

  where

  - `applications` is table that contains list of all your applications
  - `oper_x_app` is table that contains list of applications available to certain users (because, you might want to allow one user to access 2 applications, another user to access some other 3 applications, etc.)

  What's important here is the `&SESSION.` part of code (see line #4); without it, it won't work.

  That *menu* page (in my application) looks like this:

  [image]

Then, in each of those applications,

- go to Shared Components > Authentication Schemes > choose Current schema > Session Cookie Attributes > enter the same cookie name (`MY_SSO_COOKIE`) into "Cookie name"
- create new navigation menu entry called e.g. "Main application" whose target type is URL: `http://server_name:8084/apex/f?p=118:1:&SESSION.` (important part is again `%SESSION.`)

That's it; now you log in into the main application and move around without new logins.

Comment: sorry for a stupid question, but where i shoud write this code?

Comment: On a page - in "main" application - that is used as a **menu**. That's how I did that. Maybe you have a different approach; if so, try to make it work based on what I wrote.

Comment: could you make a screenshot pls((

Comment: Yes; I embedded it into answer; have a look.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did it. But i create a cards container and my icons have been lost. Is there any possibilities to solve this problem